Google Apps Script not displaying IMAGES in web app
I have tried my best, but I cannot get Google Apps Script to recognize and display my images from the following Google Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q4qRgXSq6xXhddArPCoBIuOOupRvokUd0andADCNN0Q/edit#gid=1708987569
The page looks like this:

The App Script I am using is found here:
https://script.google.com/home/projects/19s4gBBgyIoNxfizdlopdsPBTgVAQ_bvqVZJZ6opWuSfrPsFXAnLEdk96/edit
It represents the table decently well and allows someone to add data and submit it in field D2 & D3 because I had a search box in there (which I removed for simplicity's sake). But it does not show the images.
Can you help me figure out how to show images on the fly? This will be the results page from a Search, so it needs to sense whatever image is there and show it. I am open to coding the images in a different way in the sheet to make them more accessible. I'm basically willing to do almost anything to make this work dynamically.
Here is the code:
const sheetId = "1q4qRgXSq6xXhddArPCoBIuOOupRvokUd0andADCNN0Q";
const sheetName = "MAIN";

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(getHtml());
}

function getHtml() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  if (!sheet) {
    return 'Error: Sheet not found.';
  }

  // Get all data from the sheet (display values to evaluate formulas)
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const images = sheet.getImages();

  // Create a map of images by their row and column
  let imageMap = {};
  images.forEach(image => {
    const row = image.getAnchorCell().getRow();
    const column = image.getAnchorCell().getColumn();
    const imageData = image.getAs("image/jpeg").getBytes();
    console.log("Image data:", imageData); // Add this logging statement
    imageMap[`${row}-${column}`] = imageData;
  });

  // Create HTML form and table
  var htmlOutput = "<html><head><style>";
  htmlOutput += "body { font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; }"; // Add CSS for font
  htmlOutput += "table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }"; // Add CSS for table
  htmlOutput += "th, td { border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px; }"; // Add CSS for table cells
  htmlOutput += "th { background-color: #f2f2f2; }"; // Add CSS for table header
  htmlOutput += "</style></head><body>";
  
  htmlOutput += "<form id='searchForm' onsubmit='return submitForm()'>";
  
  // Add input fields for D2 and D3 at the top
  htmlOutput += "<div>";
  htmlOutput += "<label for='userInputD2'>Enter value for D2: </label>";
  htmlOutput += "<input type='text' id='userInputD2' placeholder='Enter value for D2'><br>";
  htmlOutput += "<label for='userInputD3'>Enter value for D3: </label>";
  htmlOutput += "<input type='text' id='userInputD3' placeholder='Enter value for D3'><br>";
  htmlOutput += "<button type='submit'>Submit</button>";
  htmlOutput += "</div><br>";

  htmlOutput += "<table>";

  // Create table headers from the first row
  htmlOutput += "<tr>";
  for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
    htmlOutput += "<th>" + data[0][i] + "</th>";
  }
  htmlOutput += "</tr>";

  // Create table rows with data, excluding rows 2 and 3
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (i === 1 || i === 2) continue; // Skip rows 2 and 3
    htmlOutput += "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
      var value = data[i][j];
      // Check if there's an image in the cell
      var imageKey = `${i + 1}-${j + 1}`;
      if (imageMap[imageKey]) {
        var base64Image = Utilities.base64Encode(imageMap[imageKey]);
        value = "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64Image + "' alt='Image' />";
      } else if (value.startsWith('=') && value.indexOf('IMAGE("') !== -1) {
        // Extract the image URL from the formula
        var imageUrl = extractImageUrlFromFormula(value);
        value = "<img src='" + imageUrl + "' alt='Image' />";
      }

      htmlOutput += "<td>" + (value ? value : "") + "</td>"; // Display blank cells as empty
    }
    htmlOutput += "</tr>";
  }
  htmlOutput += "</table>";

  htmlOutput += "</form>";

  // Include client-side script for form submission and data refresh
  htmlOutput += "<script>";
  htmlOutput += "function submitForm() {";
  htmlOutput += "var userInputD2 = document.getElementById('userInputD2').value;";
  htmlOutput += "var userInputD3 = document.getElementById('userInputD3').value;";
  htmlOutput += "google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(refreshPage).updateCells([userInputD2, userInputD3]);";
  htmlOutput += "return false;";
  htmlOutput += "}";
  htmlOutput += "function refreshPage() {";
  htmlOutput += "google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateHtml).getHtml();";
  htmlOutput += "}";
  htmlOutput += "function updateHtml(html) {";
  htmlOutput += "document.body.innerHTML = html;";
  htmlOutput += "}";
  htmlOutput += "</script>";

  htmlOutput += "</body></html>";

  return htmlOutput;
}

function updateCells(values) {
  try {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
    sheet.getRange("D2").setValue(values[0]);
    sheet.getRange("D3").setValue(values[1]);
    return "Cells D2 and D3 updated successfully.";
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error updating cells:", error);
    return "Error updating cells.";
  }
}
function extractImageUrlFromFormula(formula) {
  // Regex to match URLs with or without quotes
  const imageUrlRegex = /IMAGE\("([^"]+)\"|\s+([^ ]+)\)/;
  const match = formula.match(imageUrlRegex);

  // Return the captured URL group if found, otherwise return an empty string
  return match ? match[1] || match[2] : ""; // Check both capture groups
}


Your goal is not clear. Your first screenshot is the result of a formula in D1 in tab MAIN: why would you ask the user to make sudmission in D2 & D3 which will give you #REF! in the sheet? You need to review how the question is posted to ensure your ultimate goal is clear and your current struggle is also clear.

I mention in the writeup that I simplified the page -- that it is a search page, but my issue is with the results. I removed the first 5 rows, which contain the search, so you can see just the results. Therefore, ignore the input of D2 & D3. My goal is to see the images.

Try using dataUrls.

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About My goal is to see the images., I think that the images can be retrieved. But, unfortunately, I cannot imagine your expected result. So, I cannot propose a modified script. I apologize for this situation. Can you provide your expected result? I would like to think of a solution by correctly understanding your question.
